# php giving value different that it mentions

Tags: php, cookies

Got a problem here with PHP.

I used setcookie() to store a value when someone logs in. the value of the cookie is "fred" and its name is "name" and in another page i use the cookie I invoke $_cookie['name'] and print it and appears "fred". But the issue is when I use the cookie variable on a query.

```
$name = $_cookie['name'];
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE '$name' ORDER BY id ");
```

if i do this, $name does not arrive as fred, i know this because i replaced the $name value on the query to fred and the query works! So clearly theres a problem getting the variable as a clean string. I tried strlen to get out the last character if there is a blank space, i also tried with ltrim(), rtrim(). Got no more ideas. help please!

Comment: What happens when you run `echo "SELECT * FROM names WHERE name LIKE '$name' ORDER BY id ";`? Also, `$name = $_COOKIE['name'];` Why are you doing a `LIKE` search with no wildcards? Use `name = '$name'`

Comment: Same result. I tried also with equals not like and the same result. if i run the query in a echo i got an error "Resource id #5"

Comment: what is displayed when u `echo $name` above

Comment: It displays "fred" correctly, but it not arrives like that on the query

Comment: Also `$_cookie` is not `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver know it, just not wasting time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this error because I was writing the query like this:

```
SELECT ALL FROM USERS WHERE NAME LIKE "NAME" ORDER BY ID
```

instead of:

```
SELECT BLABLA WHERE BLA LIKE 'BLA' ORDER BLA
```